# Can I manually run scripts on App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Is there a way to run something like "node testscript.js" remotely?

If not, how do you test particular functions on App Engine? I can test them locally, but there are difference when running on App Engine.

Comment: No, scripts cannot be run manually on app engine. If it is running fine on local then  production should also run. Can you describe the difference being observed for better diagnosis.

Comment: I think the biggest difference is that requests timeout on App Engine and not locally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to run something in App Engine, you will have to deploy it, and whenever you make changes to the source code, you will have to redeploy it again to be able to run the updated code on App Engine. You should test your application in local thoroughly to be sure it will be working as expected when deployed.

With respect to the timeouts, please keep in mind that there are two environments: flexible and standard, where [the timeout deadlines differ (60 sec for standard vs 60 min for flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features). Also, you can have long-running requests on App Engine standard if you use the [manual scaling option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling).

You might also look at [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), depending on what your scripts do. Some of the options to trigger Cloud Functions are [HTTP requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) or [Direct Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/direct).